# Problema com Retorno de Método Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const data_ = () => {
    let array = []
    fs.createReadStream('./files/treinamento.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data', (data) => {
            array.push(data)
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log(array)
        })
}
```

Utilizando console.log obtenho retorno com os valores que quero, mas substituindo o console por return a função me devolve um array vazio. Alguem poderia me dar uma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível fazer `return` dessa função porque ela é assíncrona. O que tens de fazer é encadear funções.

Ou seja, se tens uma função que precisa desse resultado, tens de a chamar, passando-lhe os dados que precisa dentro desse `end`. Algo assim:

```js
function usarData(arr) {
  // esta função será chamada quando a array estiver pronta.
  console.log(arr);
}

const data_ = (fn) => {
  let array = []
  fs.createReadStream('./files/treinamento.csv')
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => {
      array.push(data)
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      fn(array)
    })
}

data_(usarData);
```